# How can I install shareit on Ubuntu16.04?

Tags: software-installation, wine, shareit

How can I install *shareit* for Ubuntu 16.04 on my Leno laptop?

FYI: I have already installed "Wine Windows program loader" on my system and loaded one or two other Windows applications.

But I would like exact "ubuntu direct steps" to get *shareit* on my system. What, exactly, should I do to install it?

Comment: The issue may not even be able to install it (this you get with Wine), but if it will be able to connect your smartphone to the computer. It does not hurt to try

Comment: What makes you think there are "ubuntu direct steps"?